# Linking components to local in-project documentation

Tags: unity, c#, documentation

Unity 2020.3.31f1, Windows 10.

Is it possible to use local documentation, e.g. HTML files in the Assets folder of a project, as the Help URL for a component?

If so, what path should I put in the `HelpURL` annotation?

I tried the following annotations with a file at *Assets/Documentation/Test.html*, but all of them led to the same behavior of nothing happening when I click the help icon for the component in the inspector:

```
[HelpURL("Assets/Documentation/Test.html")]
[HelpURL("/Assets/Documentation/Test.html")]
[HelpURL("../Documentation/Test.html")] // relative path to script
[HelpURL("file://Assets/Documentation/Test.html")]
[HelpURL("file:///Assets/Documentation/Test.html")]
[HelpURL("Documentation/Test.html")]
[HelpURL("/Documentation/Test.html")]
[HelpURL("file://Documentation/Test.html")]
[HelpURL("file:///Documentation/Test.html")]
```

I couldn't think of anything else.

Fwiw I added "html" to the extension list at *Project Settings → Editor → C# Project Generation → Additional extensions to include*; but its presence there doesn't affect the behavior.

If this isn't possible, then how is component documentation usually distributed with a package? Is it *always* distributed online? But then, what if hosting it online isn't appropriate or feasible?